# How to enable disabled fields using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function disableField()
 {
 var Count = $('#dataTable tr').length;
 if (Count == 2){
     $("input").not('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
 }else{
  $("input").prop('disabled', false);
 }
}
    
//--------------------------------------------------
    
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
var cindex = 0;
var quicklink = '' ;
$(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(addrow) {
  var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
  
  if(count || !$('.id_100 option[value=code]').attr('selected','selected')){
    alert("Please fill the current row");
    return false;
  }
 
  
    var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
    var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
    cindex++;
 $clone.find(':input').not('select').not('.DeleteButton').val('').attr('disabled', true);
    $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
    //update ids of elements in row
    $clone.find("*").each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            if(id != ""){

            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 2) {
   this.id = this.name + (cindex);
            }
            }
    });
   $tr.after($clone);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="mainbox" class="mainbox"><tr><td>
 <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
 <div class="abcd"> <!--mainbox middlepanel start-->
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="maintable" class="maintable">
   <tr>
    <td valign="top">
     <div id="pageheadingpanel">
      <div id="pageheading">Quick Link Widget Configuration</div>
      <div id="pageheadingdate"><xsl:call-template name="formatted_date"/></div>
     </div>
    </td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td height="100%" valign="top">
     <div class="y_scroll"  id="contentarea">
      <div class="contentarea"><!--contentarea  start-->
       <span id="box" class="box"> <!--rounded curve/border  start-->
       <div class="middlepanel"> <!--contentarea  box middlepanel start-->
 <div style="display:block"  id="textBox1" >
   <span id="box1" class="box"> 
    <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
    <div class="middlepanel"> 
    


<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
   <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
    <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="id0">
 
      <td>
   <div class="id_100">
    <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <xsl:for-each select="values from local db">
   <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description"/>
   <option value="{description}">
    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
   </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </select>
     </div> </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
  
      </td>
      <td>
        <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
  
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
        
      </td>
   <td>
   <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton"  type="button" />
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>

  </ul>
 
</div>
```

I have a table with a drop-down column in it. Whenever i change the values of drop-down my corresponding fields get enabled. The problem i am getting is if i change the values of my drop-down of previous row the columns of current row also get enabled.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
Edit:I have added 'Add Row' function too in my code.

Comment: Can you please put your code in snippet?

Comment: I have updated in Snippet.Please check

Comment: what is jQuery version?

Comment: @Saurav Can you please explain your problem in brief? Because i couldn't get your point.

Comment: when i select my 'Select' field the corresponding fields get enabled (which are disabled initially). The problem is if i add one more row and change the value of my first row select , the fields of 2nd row gets enabled which is a bug in my code.The jQuery version is 3.3.1

Comment: @Saurav Please check this link. https://jsfiddle.net/sa1fkhL4/3/   If any changes please let me know.

Comment: The fiddle you shared is not working.I have updated my code in the snippet.Please do have a look.

Comment: @Saurav you want to enable `delete row` button when selectbox value change to empty because the select box has 2 values: select and empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some changes in your **disableField** function. Pass parameter(this) **disableField(this)** in that function on chnage event.

```js
function disableField(elem)
 {
 var Count = $('#dataTable tr').length;
 if (Count == 2){
 $(elem).closest('tr').find("input").not('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else{
  $(elem).closest('tr').find("input").prop('disabled', false);
  }}
    
    //--------------------------------------------------
    
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
var cindex = 0;
var quicklink = '' ;
$(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(addrow) {
  var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
  
  if(count || !$('.id_100 option[value=code]').attr('selected','selected')){
    alert("Please fill the current row");
    return false;
  }
 
  
    var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
    var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
    cindex++;
 $clone.find(':input').not('select').attr('disabled', true);
    $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
    //update ids of elements in row
    $clone.find("*").each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            if(id != ""){

            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 2) {
   this.id = this.name + (cindex);
            }
            }
    });
   $tr.after($clone);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="mainbox" class="mainbox"><tr><td>
 <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
 <div class="abcd"> <!--mainbox middlepanel start-->
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="maintable" class="maintable">
   <tr>
    <td valign="top">
     <div id="pageheadingpanel">
      <div id="pageheading">Quick Link Widget Configuration</div>
      <div id="pageheadingdate"><xsl:call-template name="formatted_date"/></div>
     </div>
    </td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td height="100%" valign="top">
     <div class="y_scroll"  id="contentarea">
      <div class="contentarea"><!--contentarea  start-->
       <span id="box" class="box"> <!--rounded curve/border  start-->
       <div class="middlepanel"> <!--contentarea  box middlepanel start-->
 <div style="display:block"  id="textBox1" >
   <span id="box1" class="box"> 
    <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
    <div class="middlepanel"> 
    


<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
   <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
    <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="id0">
 
      <td>
   <div class="id_100">
    <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField(this)" >
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <xsl:for-each select="values from local db">
   <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description"/>
   <option value="{description}">
    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
   </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </select>
     </div> </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
  
      </td>
      <td>
        <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
  
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
        
      </td>
   <td>
   <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton"  type="button" />
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>

  </ul>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep. Thanks for your answer. I have been testing the code and found out that whenever i am adding a new row and changing the 'Select' field my first row delete button is not getting enabled.Please help.Thanks

Comment: Run the code in Snippet. Its also not working in the snippet. Also when i am adding the third row my delete button of third row is already enabled.Please check.

Comment: you have do that in your add button code, so please verify first what do you want.

Comment: If i have more than one row only then my first row 'Delete Button' should get activated. And except for first row ,my all corresponding fields should get enabled when value of 'Select' field is changed.

Comment: can you please check?

Comment: The first row delete button is not getting enabled.

Answer (score 1):

All in all there is to much extraneous code so the following answer has different code yet can be applied to the clunky code provided in question. I recommend that your code be more streamlined like the following demo provided in this answer.

Here's some suggestions:

- If you are using multiple form controls (ex. `<button>`, `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc), wrap everything into a `<form>`
- If you have multiple tags (aka elements) that the user can `click`, `submit`, `reset`, `change`, `input`, etc register the events to the `<form>`
- In order to find the exact form control that was clicked, changed, etc. use the [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property to find it or `this` keyword and the [`Event.data`](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/) parameter.

  ```
  $('form selector').on('event type', Event.data, callback function)
  ```
- The `#id` and `[name]` attributes are unnecessary unless you are using certain Web APIs such as [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) or [**HTMLFormElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)
- Never use event attributes (ex `onchange="callback()"`) when using jQuery. Use the proper jQuery method or [`.on()` method](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

  ```
  // jQuery method
  $(selector).click(callback)

  // .on() method
  $(selector).on('click', callback)
  ```

---

Minor details:

- The `[type]` attribute does not apply to the `<select>` tag.
- Use `<th>` instead of `<td>` within `<thead>`
- `[maxlength]` of `500` is ridiculous. Use `<textarea>` instead of `<input>`

---

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
/*
Register form.io to the 'submit', 'click', and 'change' events
Note the callback function does not have `()` suffixed because it would be 
interpreted as: "run function now"
The callback function doesn't run immediately it runs when a registered event is triggered.
*/
$('.io').on('submit click change', eventHandler);

// Define the counter
let counter = 0;

// Always pass the Event Object when defining a callback function
function eventHandler(event) {
  
  // The Event Object has several properties...
  // Get the type of event triggered (ie submit, change, or click)
  let eType = event.type;
  
  /*
  Get the origin element of event 
    if 'submit' target will be <form>
    if 'click' target will be <button>
    if 'change' target will be <select>
  */  
  let eNode = event.target;
  
  // Pass the event type through a switch() function...
  switch (eType) {
    
    // if type is 'submit'...
    case 'submit':
      // Create a deep clone of the first row 
      let clone = $('.grid tr:first-child').clone(true, true);
      // Add clone as the last child of the <tbody>
      $('.grid').append(clone);
      // On .each() elment with class '.data' found within the clone...
      clone.find('.data').each(function(i) {
        // disable it
        this.disabled = true;
        // remove its value
        this.value = '';
      });
      
      // Increment the counter by 1 
      counter++;
      // Dereference the clone and assign id as row+counter
      clone[0].id = `row${counter}`;
      
      /*
      Prevent default behavior:
        Reset <form>
        Send data to a server
      */
      event.preventDefault();
      // Stop event from bubbling any further up the event chain
      event.stopPropagation();
      // ...otherwise skip this case and continue onto the next case
      break;
    
    // if type is 'click'...
    case 'click':
      // if the clicked element (ie <button>) has class: '.del'...
      if ($(eNode).hasClass('del')) {
        // Get the clicked <button>'s ancestor <tr>
        let row = $(eNode).closest('tr');
        // if that <tr> is NOT the first <tr>...
        if (row.index() !== 0) {
          // remove the <tr>
          row.remove();
        }
      }
      event.stopPropagation();
      break;
    
    // if type is 'change'...
    case 'change':
      // if changed element (ie <select>) class is '.type'...
      if ($(eNode).hasClass('type')) {
        // Get the changed <select>'s ancestor <tr>
        let row = $(eNode).closest('tr');
        // if changed <select>'s value is NOT "X" return true otherwise return false
        let pick = eNode.value !== "X" ? true : false;
        /*
        On .each() element with class .data within the <tr>
        disable the .data if <select>'s value is "X"
        Otherwise enable the .data
        and then remove the .data value
        */
        row.find('.data').each(function(i) {
          this.disabled = !pick;
          this.value = '';
        });
      }
      event.stopPropagation();
      break;

    default:
      event.stopPropagation();
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 3vw/1.2 Arial
}

form {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 10px auto
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 4px;
  width: 90vw
}

th:first-of-type {
  width: 20%
}

th:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 35%
}

th:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 35%
}

th:last-of-type {
  width: 10%
}

td {
  padding: 0 8px
}

select,
textarea,
button {
  display: block;
  min-width: 97%;
  min-height: 1.2rem;
  font-size: initial;
}

select {
  padding: 2px 0 2px 2px
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden
}
```

```html
<form class='io'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Desciption</th>
        <th>Image/URL</th>
        <th><button>➕</button></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='grid'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class='type'>
            <option value="X" default></option>
            <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
            <option value="PRO">Promos</option>
            <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
            <option value="VID">Videos</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><textarea class='desc data' rows='1' cols='20' disabled></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class='urls data' rows='1' cols='20' disabled></textarea></td>
        <td><button class='del' type='button'>❌</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and thanks for taking out time to explain everything but since I am a newbie in front-end so i didn't get most part of this but thanks anyway.

Comment: If you can help me with this. I've  been trying prepend the values coming from db with '#' . Since i am tokenizing the value on the basis of '#' and '~' for the second screen

Comment: Try `<option value="#{description}">`

Comment: You're an God bro.Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem. Happy coding, @Saurav.